# Grouping Shapes in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, drawing, swift5

I have a face shape drawn in swiftUI. The face is a circle and eyes are two circles . I want to group these three Circles as one Single shape so that when I move face shape the eyes also should move with the face also I want to draw the eyes based on relative face circle coordinate and not the coordinate system of rect of draw func.

Comment: Would you show your code?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var x: CGFloat = 100
  @State var y: CGFloat = 100


  var body: some View {
      VStack{
          //Shape Group
          Group{
              //Put your Shape here
              ZStack{
                  Rectangle().fill(Color.green)
                  Circle().fill(Color.blue)
              }.frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center )
          }
          .position(x: self.x, y: self.y)
        
          //Slider for position
          HStack{
              Text("x: \(x)")
              Slider(value: $x, in: 0...400, step: 1).padding(.horizontal, 10)
          }
          HStack{
              Text("y: \(y)")
              Slider(value: $y, in: 0...500, step: 1).padding(.horizontal, 10)
          }
      }
   }
}
```